# GCalendar: Fee / Busy-Setting per Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

which command is responsible for the fee/busy-Setting in GCalendar?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/ has all of the enumerated properties, busy/free doesn't seem to be one you can get at from calendar service. I personally put in "interrupt ok" to a bunch of my block names.

Comment: What you mean with: "interrupt ok" ??

Comment: In the name of the blocks I make with my script, they are just named "Coding - Interrupt OK" so people can know it is ok to bother me (free) rather than busy.